# Can I make direct citation on Kindle books?

Tags: kindle, amazon, kdp

Recently, I had serious problems with Amazon Kindle: I have used my own work, from my blog, and images free for use. However, they accused me of copyright infringement. Blocked my account, after a failed to prove that work was mine, I tried. Now, my account is working, but I am on a black list.
Thus, I am afraid to lose my account, with more than 6 books published, and several downloads, hard work!
Can I cite directly?
Academically, okay, we do it all the time!
but what about Amazon KDP?
The citation is from a copyrighted book!

Comment: Quotation are usually allowed under fair use, but they must not be too long and should be marked as such. Without looking at your work, it is difficult to check it this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing a message to the U.S. Copyright Office, link

https://www.copyright.gov/help/
and try to find a solution for you, a fair use, reading information from the link :

https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/

You can also ask (As I did)  a lawyer(5 GBP trial few days) using website :
[https://my-secure.justanswer.co.uk/dashboard?state=None&al=1&utm_source=mar&utm_medium=email&utm_content=jalogo_im&utm_campaign=nps_ppq_a&r=sme|pdcDlvJaUkNPSSurveyPPQ|116491656|ln=jalogo_im](https://my-secure.justanswer.co.uk/dashboard?state=None&al=1&utm_source=mar&utm_medium=email&utm_content=jalogo_im&utm_campaign=nps_ppq_a&r=sme%7CpdcDlvJaUkNPSSurveyPPQ%7C116491656%7Cln=jalogo_im)

It is important to know why your account was blocked temporarily. Any idea what you did ?

Comment: Any idea what you did ? it was solved, but they found part of my work online, on my own blog. Tried to explain, but no success. Also images, I have used free images, but they failed to accept. Now, it seems okay, I have published the book with quotation, direct.